# Get the top most element for any element in chain (tree) in Oracle Sql

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, hierarchical-data

Consider the following structure with some nodes:

```
        1
        /\
       2  3
       |  |
       4  5
       |  |
       6  7   
       |
       8
```

or

```
with mydata as (
 select 8 id ,6 id_before, 400 datum from dual union all
 select 6,4, 300 from dual union all
 select 4, 2, 200 from dual union all
 select 2,1, 10 from dual union all
 select 3, 1, 60 from dual union all
 select 5, 3, 800 from dual union all
 select 7, 5, 900 from dual 
)
```

Now given the `id` of the node I want to get the `root node id`

e.g. for node `7` root note `1`, for `5` root node `1` for `4` root node `1` etc.

I tried something like this:

```
select id, id_before,datum, SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(id_before,'/') as path,
SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(datum,'/') as datapath,
level,
CONNECT_BY_ROOT id_before
     from mydata
       where id=7
      connect by  id_before = prior id
```

with disappointing results:

```
7   5   900 /1/3/5  /60/800/900 3   1
7   5   900 /3/5    /800/900    2   3
7   5   900 /5      /900        1   5
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [MRE] including your expected output and a description (in English, not code) of how you expect to reach that output. Stating "with disappointing results" and asking "how to fix this" is not constructive as it does not tell us what is disappointing or how you expect it to be fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF` as a filter to find the root element:

**Oracle Setup**:

```sql
CREATE TABLE mydata ( id, id_before, datum ) as
 select 8, 6, 400 from dual union all
 select 6, 4, 300 from dual union all
 select 4, 2, 200 from dual union all
 select 2, 1,  10 from dual union all
 select 3, 1,  60 from dual union all
 select 5, 3, 800 from dual union all
 select 7, 5, 900 from dual;
```

**Query**:

```sql
SELECT CONNECT_BY_ROOT( id ) AS id,
       id_before AS root_id,
       SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH( id, ',' ) || ',' || id_before AS path
FROM   mydata
WHERE  CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF = 1
CONNECT BY id = PRIOR id_before;
```

**Output**:

> ```
> ID | ROOT_ID | PATH      
> -: | ------: | :---------
>  2 |       1 | ,2,1      
>  3 |       1 | ,3,1      
>  4 |       1 | ,4,2,1    
>  5 |       1 | ,5,3,1    
>  6 |       1 | ,6,4,2,1  
>  7 |       1 | ,7,5,3,1  
>  8 |       1 | ,8,6,4,2,1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=5eb5f0d29b2bb751154978052f625370)*

Answer (score 0):

This topic helped me a lot today.
Needed to find a way to get whole tree by item in the middle.
It's fair to share results here, even after 2 years of accepted answer.

```
create table ref (id number not null, prvni varchar2(1), druhy varchar2(1));

insert into ref (id, prvni, druhy) values (1, 'B', 'A');
insert into ref (id, prvni, druhy) values (2, 'C', 'A');
insert into ref (id, prvni, druhy) values (3, 'D', 'C');
insert into ref (id, prvni, druhy) values (4, 'E', 'A');
insert into ref (id, prvni, druhy) values (5, 'F', 'C');
insert into ref (id, prvni, druhy) values (6, 'G', 'F');
insert into ref (id, prvni, druhy) values (7, 'x', 'y');
insert into ref (id, prvni, druhy) values (8, 'z', 'v');
insert into ref (id, prvni, druhy) values (9, 'w', 'u');

create table zpr (pismeno varchar2(1), typ varchar2(6));

insert into zpr (pismeno, typ) values ('A', 'ORDERS');
insert into zpr (pismeno, typ) values ('B', 'ORDRSP');
insert into zpr (pismeno, typ) values ('C', 'DESADV');
insert into zpr (pismeno, typ) values ('D', 'RECADV');
insert into zpr (pismeno, typ) values ('E', 'RETANN');
insert into zpr (pismeno, typ) values ('F', 'INVOIC');
insert into zpr (pismeno, typ) values ('G', 'INVOIC');
insert into zpr (pismeno, typ) values ('x', 'APERAK');
insert into zpr (pismeno, typ) values ('y', 'APERAK');
insert into zpr (pismeno, typ) values ('z', 'APERAK');
insert into zpr (pismeno, typ) values ('u', 'APERAK');
insert into zpr (pismeno, typ) values ('v', 'APERAK');
insert into zpr (pismeno, typ) values ('w', 'APERAK');

-- recursion
WITH rcte(prvni,druhy,typ,lvl) AS
 (SELECT r1.prvni, r1.druhy, a1.typ, 1 AS lvl
    FROM ref r1, zpr a1
   WHERE (r1.prvni = 'B' OR r1.druhy = 'B')
     AND a1.pismeno = r1.druhy
  
  UNION ALL
  
  SELECT r2.prvni, r2.druhy, a2.typ, lvl + 1 AS lvl
    FROM ref r2
   INNER JOIN zpr a2
      ON a2.pismeno = r2.druhy
   INNER JOIN rcte rc
      ON r2.prvni = rc.druhy),
orders AS
 (SELECT * FROM rcte WHERE typ = 'ORDERS')
SELECT prvni,
       z1.typ prvni_typ,
       connect_by_root(druhy) AS druhy,
       z2.typ druhy_typ,
       sys_connect_by_path(druhy, ' => ') || ' => ' || prvni AS path,
       sys_connect_by_path(z2.typ, ' => ') AS typy
  FROM ref, zpr z1, zpr z2
 WHERE ref.prvni = z1.pismeno
   AND ref.druhy = z2.pismeno
--and CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF = 1
CONNECT BY PRIOR prvni = druhy
 START WITH ref.druhy IN (SELECT druhy FROM orders);
```

[Here's the fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5a3181/38): http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5a3181/38